# Given all zip codes in the US, their latitude and longitude. How can I calculate zip codes in between a certain mile radius?

Tags: trigonometry

Summary: I am creating a website, this site functions off a user searching a zip code and seeing results in that zip. I am trying to add a feature that allows them to see posts within a certain mile radius of their zip(feature you see on real estate sites, job boards, etc). As you can tell I spend most of my time on stack's programming sites, but this I feel is a math issue, so I am hoping someone can help me.

I am have a file with every zip code in the US and their respective latitude and longitude. For example: `Zip Code = 99929` has `latitude =56.370751` and `longitude = -131.693301`. So say a user has searched zip code '99929' and wants to see all posts within 20 miles of this zip code. If you read this far and already have a solution you can skip what is below, below is an explanation of what I have so far written in the Python programming language.

The following can take a starting latitude and longitude, along with an ending latitude and longitude, and calculate the distance between them:

```
slat = radians(float(input("Starting latitude: "))) # to explain this :input() gets the starting latitude, float() converts this to a floating point number and radians() converts this from degrees to radians
slon = radians(float(input("Ending longitude: ")))
elat = radians(float(input("Starting latitude: ")))
elon = radians(float(input("Ending longitude: ")))


#calculations
dist_in_km = 6371.01 * acos(sin(slat)*sin(elat) + cos(slat)*cos(elat)*cos(slon - elon))
miles_per_kilometer = 0.621371;
dist_in_miles = dist_in_km * miles_per_kilometer
```

Can anyone think of a way to implement this knowing the `slat`, `slon` and `dist_in_miles` before hand (20 miles in the above example), so that instead of calculating `dist_in_miles` it determines the `elat` and `elon`?

Thanks in advance for any help, this has been driving me crazy.

Comment: I would personally prefer to do all of my calculations in terms of cartesian coordinates (*and the assumption for simplification that the earth is a sphere*).  Cartesian distance between points $(X,Y,Z)$ and $(x,y,z)$ is simply $\sqrt{(X-x)^2+(Y-y)^2+(Z-z)^2}$.  You should be able to define functions to convert lat-lon pairs to (x,y,z) coordinates and vice versa.

Comment: Are you looking for a program that on input of slat, slon, and dist, can output elat and elon?  Note that there are many possible elat, elon pairs that are distance dist away from any given slat, slon

Comment: Infinitely many in fact, a whole circle around the initial point.  Some points will be easier to calculate (*e.g. where latitude stayed the same and we changed only longitude*), but describing a circle on the sphere in terms of latitude-longitude pairs is incredibly frustrating to do, far easier to do it with cartesian coordinates instead.

Comment: @rikhavshah yes, if I have the final elat and elon I believe it would be easy to get all the zip codes that have latitudes and longitudes between the start and end points from my db.

Comment: @JMoravitz I appreciate the response, but I would be lying if I said I comprehended any of that, I will try and look into cartesian coordinates though

Comment: Yes, it would be easy to pull entries from your database that have latitude values between `slat` and `elat` as well has have longitude values between `slon` and `elon`, but that doesn't sound like what you are after.  It sounded like you were wanting to describe all locations within a set radius from your initial point.  All you are doing is describing all points within a rectangular projection onto a sphere with one corner described by (slat,slon) and the other corner described by (elat,elon).  For example, if (elat,elon) occured straight east, you only are finding points to the east.

Comment: I would think you should start by calculating what the possible ranges for the latitude and longitude are.  You can filter all the posting in your database inside these limits, and then calculate the actual distance.  For example, $20$ miles is about $0.3$ degrees of latitude, so if the starting point is at $45^\circ$ W latitude, you are only interest in points with latitude between $44.7^\circ$ W and $45.3^\circ$ W.  Of course, the number of degrees of longitude equivalent to $20$ miles depends of the latitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math answer:

Do calculations with the map as a globe rather than a rectangle.  Distance between two grid points on a rectangular map of the world is messy and complicated since grid squares do not represent the same area despite often being pictured as taking the same area.  Keep everything within a set distance from your location where distance is calculated directly.

---

Programming implementation example:

Assuming you are taking in your data about zipcode locations as a *.csv and it contains columns 'lat' and 'lon' to denote position (*these can be changed easily enough to fit your specific needs*)

```
import scipy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def convert_latlon_to_cartesian(lat,lon):

   x = scipy.math.cos(lon * np.pi / 180) * scipy.math.cos(lat * np.pi / 180)

   y = scipy.math.cos(lat * np.pi / 180) * scipy.math.sin(lon * np.pi / 180)

   z = scipy.math.sin(lat * np.pi / 180)

   x *= 3959
   y *= 3959
   z *= 3959

   return (x,y,z)

def convert_cartesian_to_latlon(x,y,z):

   r = scipy.math.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)

   lat = scipy.math.asin(z / r) * 180 / np.pi

   lon = scipy.math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / np.pi

   if lat > 180:
       lat -= 360

   return (lat,lon)

def cartesian_distance(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2):
    return scipy.math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2+(z1-z2)**2)
```

---

```
with open('MyZipCodeFile.csv', mode='r') as csvfile:
   zipcodesdf = pd.read_csv(csvfile)

slat = input('What latitude-longitude would you like to search at?\nLat: ')
slon = input('Lon: ')
dist = input('What mile radius would you like to limit results to?\nDist: ')

sx,sy,sz = convert_latlon_to_cartesian(slat,slon)

temporarydf = zipcodesdf
temporarydf['x']=''
temporarydf['y']=''
temporarydf['z']=''
temporarydf['dist']=''

#populate new fields with cartesian (x,y,z) coordinates and calculate distance from original point
for index,row in temporarydf.iterrows():
    row['x'],row['y'],row['z'] = convert_latlon_to_cartesian(row['lat'],row['lon'])
    row['dist'] = cartesian_distance(sx,sy,sz,row['x'],row['y'],row['z'])

#get back a dataframe containing only entries within set distance of target
outputdf = temporarydf.loc[temporarydf['dist'] <= dist]
```